# Fastest way to create a numpy array with consecutive integer but ignore specific number

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I need to generate a numpy array fill with consecutive numbers but ignore a specific number.

For example, I need a numpy array between 0 to 5 but ignore 3. The result will be `[0,1,2,4,5,]`.

My current solution is very slow when the array size I need is large. Here is my testing code and it took `2m34s` on my i7-6770 machine with `Python 3.6.5`.

```
import numpy as np

length = 150000

for _ in range(10000):
    skip = np.random.randint(length)
    indexing = np.asarray([i for i in range(length) if i != skip])
```

Hence, I would like to know if there's better one. Thanks

Comment: Why are you making 10000 arrays & throwing them all away except the final one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of ignoring a number, split your array into two ranges, leaving the number you're ignoring out. Then use `np.arange` to make the arrays and concatenate them.

```
def range_with_ignore(start, stop, ignore):
    return np.concatenate([
        np.arange(start, ignore),
        np.arange(ignore + 1, stop)
    ])
```

Comment: Wow! Your solution is really fast. It only took 1.4 seconds!! Thank yo so much!!